# MSUM function error in OBIEE

Tags: function, obiee

I have a question about MSUM function in OBIEE. My data are illustrated in the following figure.
[image: Figure]

As you can see, the problem is that the MSUM function has summed the Measure 1
in the current month in 2016 and the previous month in 2017 rather than 2016. In 2017, it sums the data in current month and those in exact month in 2016.

How can I fix this error? Please help me. I really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not post your exact MSUM formula so no way to help you there.

From the documentation:

"MSUM
This function calculates a moving sum for the last n rows of data, inclusive of the current row.

The sum for the first row is equal to the numeric expression for the first row. The sum for the second row is calculated by taking the sum of the first two rows of data. The sum for the third row is calculated by taking the sum of the first three rows of data, and so on. When the nth row is reached, the sum is calculated based on the last n rows of data.

Syntax:

MSUM (n_expression, n)"

So...what is your "n"?

If your formula is wrong then the result will be wrong.

Comment: In my enclosed figure, I already post my formula and how the results illustrates. Please let me know if there are any problems in terms of the figure, I'll fix it. Thank Chris.

Comment: My bad. That's weird. Which exact version? And are you sure your time dimension is built correctly? Have you tried with another dimension to verify if the rollup works?

Comment: The time dimension actually is just numeric data, not time-series type. However, I tried to built another measure by using MSUM and it's successful, with the same formula. So that I do not figure out what is going on.

Comment: So there is your answer already. 3 goes back to 2. 5 goes back to 6. If you had somethijg unique like 2018-01 then it would wirk.

Comment: the problem is I didn't have. The ultimate goal is that I want to create one more column with lag of 1, so I intended to use (MSUM(2) - Current value) but it failed already. The data are not time-series type.